# Xuggler - Opening mp4 file crashed program

Tags: java, mp4, xuggler

I  have a class that implements IMediaListener. In this class I have the following method:

```
public void renderVideoWithModifications() {

        // Media Decoder to decode the input file
        mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFileName);

        // Media Encoder to encode the output file
        mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFileName, mediaReader);

        // manually set the container format
        IContainerFormat existingFormat = mediaReader.getContainer().getFormat();
        mediaWriter.getContainer().setFormat(existingFormat);

        // A connection from the reader to the writer so that the reader knows
        // where to
        // send its output
        mediaReader.addListener(this);

        // Basic file information
        duration = mediaReader.getContainer().getDuration();

        // read the file
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) {
            // Reads until it encounters an error or end of file
        }

    }
```

I am running into problems with the `while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null)` line. The program crashes and I get the following error in my console:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ee76520, pid=1952, tid=740
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle5467649014492812144.dll+0x736520]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\GeraldMurphy\Workspace\MyApp\My-Server\hs_err_pid1952.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

It is weird to me that I am running into this error since I copied this code from a different project that I have where it works fine.

I have spent a few days searching the web for any solutions and making sure that the logic for my code is the same as it is for the project that works but I haven't had any luck.

**What could be causing the crash?**

NOTE: Both `inputFileName` and `outputFileName` are mp4 files and if I call mediaReader.open() anywhere in this method I get the same crash/error.

Here is my crash log:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000ba17800):  JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=740, stack(0x000000000b6e0000,0x000000000b7e0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000e29b90, RBX=0x000000000c824170, RCX=0x0000000000e29b90, RDX=0x0000000000000009
RSP=0x000000000b7dccd0, RBP=0x0000000000e292d0, RSI=0x0000000000e2ab90, RDI=0x0000000000000004
R8 =0x000000006ee77580, R9 =0x000000006ee76490, R10=0x0000000000d3d410, R11=0x000000000c892a80
R12=0x000000000c893280, R13=0x0000000000000004, R14=0x0000000000000184, R15=0x000000006fab8f20
RIP=0x000000006ee76520, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000b7dccd0)
0x000000000b7dccd0:   000000006ee76665 000000006ee774c5
0x000000000b7dcce0:   000000006ee77505 000000006ee77545
0x000000000b7dccf0:   000000006ee77585 000000006ee79426
0x000000000b7dcd00:   000000006fa67a80 0000000000e29b90
0x000000000b7dcd10:   000000000c826630 3e54e6cebf0d09b3
0x000000000b7dcd20:   3fe0000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000b7dcd30:   40c7760000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000b7dcd40:   3fe0000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000b7dcd50:   000000000c827630 000000006ea45d24
0x000000000b7dcd60:   3f40624dd2f1a9fc 0000000000000000
0x000000000b7dcd70:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000b7dcd80:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000b7dcd90:   000000000c830530 000000006fab7320
0x000000000b7dcda0:   0000000000000000 000000000c8240d0
0x000000000b7dcdb0:   0000000000000000 0000000000e292d0
0x000000000b7dcdc0:   0000000000e292d0 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006ee76520)
0x000000006ee76500:   c4 e3 5d 0c c0 55 c5 e4 5c c8 c5 e4 58 c0 c5 fc
0x000000006ee76510:   29 01 c5 fc 29 49 20 c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000006ee76520:   c5 fc 28 51 40 c5 fc 28 59 60 c5 ec 5c fb c5 ec
0x000000006ee76530:   58 d3 c5 c4 57 3d 26 41 84 00 c5 ec c6 df be c5 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000e29b90 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000000c824170 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000e29b90 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000009 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000b7dccd0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000ba17800
RBP=0x0000000000e292d0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000e2ab90 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000006ee77580 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000006ee76490 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000d3d410 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000000c892a80 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000000c893280 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000184 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000006fab8f20 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000000b6e0000,0x000000000b7e0000],  sp=0x000000000b7dccd0,  free space=1011k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [xuggle5467649014492812144.dll+0x736520]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.IContainer_open__SWIG_1(JLcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer;Ljava/lang/String;IJLcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat;ZZ)I+0
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.open(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer$Type;Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainerFormat;ZZ)I+19
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.open()V+20
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket()Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IError;+8
j  com.my.package.media.VVVideoFileRenderer.renderVideoWithModifications()V+147
j  com.my.package.media.ExModFileWorker.doInBackground()Ljava/lang/Object;+539
j  com.my.packagevx.MyServer.export(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;+464
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+3
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+38
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+126
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;+9
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;+5
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/process/RequestProcessingContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;+28
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/process/RequestProcessingContext;)Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerResponse;+97
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run()V+57
j  org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call()Ljava/lang/Void;+4
j  org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+36
j  org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/Producer;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+2
j  org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+9
j  org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestScope$Instance;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+14
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest;)V+177
j  org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest;)V+13
j  org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpHandlerContainer.handle(Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange;)V+294
j  com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange;)V+17
j  sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange;Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/Filter$Chain;)V+121
j  com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange;)V+41
j  sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange;)V+5
j  com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange;)V+17
j  sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run()V+903
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000000000ba17800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=740, stack(0x000000000b6e0000,0x000000000b7e0000)]
  0x0000000002858800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=13876, stack(0x00000000026e0000,0x00000000027e0000)]
  0x000000000a861800 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4988, stack(0x000000000b3e0000,0x000000000b4e0000)]
  0x000000000a534800 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_in_native, id=5548, stack(0x000000000b2e0000,0x000000000b3e0000)]
  0x0000000009efe000 JavaThread "server-timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19436, stack(0x000000000b1e0000,0x000000000b2e0000)]
  0x000000000758c000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3740, stack(0x00000000092e0000,0x00000000093e0000)]
  0x0000000007574800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6420, stack(0x00000000091e0000,0x00000000092e0000)]
  0x0000000007573800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17984, stack(0x00000000090e0000,0x00000000091e0000)]
  0x0000000007558000 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=13780, stack(0x0000000008fe0000,0x00000000090e0000)]
  0x0000000007555800 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19256, stack(0x0000000008ee0000,0x0000000008fe0000)]
  0x0000000007545000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7360, stack(0x0000000008de0000,0x0000000008ee0000)]
  0x000000000753f000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17772, stack(0x00000000089a0000,0x0000000008aa0000)]
  0x000000000753c800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1616, stack(0x00000000088a0000,0x00000000089a0000)]
  0x0000000002941000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8740, stack(0x00000000087a0000,0x00000000088a0000)]
  0x0000000002938000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20728, stack(0x00000000086a0000,0x00000000087a0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000007513000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000085a0000,0x00000000086a0000] [id=532]
  0x000000000944e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000097e0000,0x00000000098e0000] [id=5096]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 145920K, used 76017K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000ff700000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 128000K, 51% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f9561078,0x00000000fd200000)
  from space 17920K, 56% used [0x00000000fe580000,0x00000000fef5b468,0x00000000ff700000)
  to   space 18944K, 0% used [0x00000000fd200000,0x00000000fd200000,0x00000000fe480000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 24068K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 27% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e17812e0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 29696K, used 29467K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dcb00000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 29696K, 99% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dcac6d38,0x00000000dcb00000)

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000005a10000,0x0000000005b40000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000005339000

Polling page: 0x0000000000e50000

Code Cache  [0x0000000002950000, 0x0000000002bc0000, 0x0000000005950000)
 total_blobs=1048 nmethods=626 adapters=381 free_code_cache=47087Kb largest_free_block=48127552

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 118.289 Thread 0x0000000007574800  655             sun.misc.ASCIICaseInsensitiveComparator::toLower (16 bytes)
Event: 118.289 Thread 0x0000000007573800  656             sun.misc.ASCIICaseInsensitiveComparator::isUpper (18 bytes)
Event: 118.290 Thread 0x0000000007573800 nmethod 656 0x0000000002b63350 code [0x0000000002b63480, 0x0000000002b634d8]
Event: 118.290 Thread 0x0000000007574800 nmethod 655 0x00000000029fff10 code [0x0000000002a00040, 0x0000000002a00098]
Event: 118.290 Thread 0x0000000007574800  657             java.util.jar.Attributes$Name::isValid (32 bytes)
Event: 118.290 Thread 0x0000000007573800  658             java.util.jar.Attributes$Name::isAlpha (30 bytes)
Event: 118.290 Thread 0x0000000007573800 nmethod 658 0x0000000002a67a90 code [0x0000000002a67bc0, 0x0000000002a67c18]
Event: 118.291 Thread 0x0000000007574800 nmethod 657 0x0000000002a67890 code [0x0000000002a679c0, 0x0000000002a67a38]
Event: 118.825 Thread 0x0000000007573800  659             java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream::ensureOpen (18 bytes)
Event: 118.826 Thread 0x0000000007573800 nmethod 659 0x0000000002a67650 code [0x0000000002a67780, 0x0000000002a677f8]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 4.054 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 37880K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000f7f80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7580000)
  from space 5120K, 89% used [0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f79fe248,0x00000000f7a80000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000f7a80000,0x00000000f7a80000,0x00000000f7f80000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 24K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0006000,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 11861K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 55% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000db9957a8,0x00000000dc300000)
Event: 4.061 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 5102K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000f7f80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 0% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f7580000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000f7a80000,0x00000000f7f7bb80,0x00000000f7f80000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7a80000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 147K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0024dd0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 11861K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 55% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000db9957a8,0x00000000dc300000)
}
Event: 5.184 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 38382K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000f7f80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7580000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000f7a80000,0x00000000f7f7bb80,0x00000000f7f80000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7a80000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 147K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0024dd0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 14010K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 65% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dbbae8f0,0x00000000dc300000)
Event: 5.198 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 5103K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000fa400000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 0% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f7580000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7a7bf98,0x00000000f7a80000)
  to   space 7168K, 0% used [0x00000000f9d00000,0x00000000f9d00000,0x00000000fa400000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 2127K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 2% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0213cf0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 14010K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 65% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dbbae8f0,0x00000000dc300000)
}
Event: 6.017 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 38383K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000fa400000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7580000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000f7580000,0x00000000f7a7bf98,0x00000000f7a80000)
  to   space 7168K, 0% used [0x00000000f9d00000,0x00000000f9d00000,0x00000000fa400000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 2127K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 2% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0213cf0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 19831K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 92% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dc15dea0,0x00000000dc300000)
Event: 6.033 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 71168K, used 7161K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000fa900000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 64000K, 0% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f9380000)
  from space 7168K, 99% used [0x00000000f9d00000,0x00000000fa3fe608,0x00000000fa400000)
  to   space 9728K, 0% used [0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9d00000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 5193K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 6% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e05126d0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 19831K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 92% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dc15dea0,0x00000000dc300000)
}
Event: 6.771 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 71168K, used 71161K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000fa900000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 64000K, 100% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9380000)
  from space 7168K, 99% used [0x00000000f9d00000,0x00000000fa3fe608,0x00000000fa400000)
  to   space 9728K, 0% used [0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9d00000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 5193K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 6% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e05126d0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 20730K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 96% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dc23e840,0x00000000dc300000)
Event: 6.801 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 73728K, used 9722K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000ff900000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 64000K, 0% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f9380000)
  from space 9728K, 99% used [0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9cfebc0,0x00000000f9d00000)
  to   space 19968K, 0% used [0x00000000fe580000,0x00000000fe580000,0x00000000ff900000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 22060K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 25% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e158b2e0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 20730K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc300000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 21504K, 96% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dc23e840,0x00000000dc300000)
}
Event: 9.244 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 73728K, used 73722K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000ff900000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 64000K, 100% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9380000)
  from space 9728K, 99% used [0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9cfebc0,0x00000000f9d00000)
  to   space 19968K, 0% used [0x00000000fe580000,0x00000000fe580000,0x00000000ff900000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 22060K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 25% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e158b2e0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 27136K, used 26996K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc880000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 27136K, 99% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dc85d090,0x00000000dc880000)
Event: 9.261 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 145920K, used 10093K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000ff700000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 128000K, 0% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000fd200000)
  from space 17920K, 56% used [0x00000000fe580000,0x00000000fef5b468,0x00000000ff700000)
  to   space 18944K, 0% used [0x00000000fd200000,0x00000000fd200000,0x00000000fe480000)
 ParOldGen       total 86528K, used 24068K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5480000, 0x00000000f5500000)
  object space 86528K, 27% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e17812e0,0x00000000e5480000)
 PSPermGen       total 27136K, used 26996K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000dc880000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 27136K, 99% used [0x00000000dae00000,0x00000000dc85d090,0x00000000dc880000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 55.433 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.440 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.443 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.461 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.540 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.572 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.592 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.852 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.855 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23
Event: 55.868 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Uncommon trap: reason=unhandled action=none pc=0x0000000002b26268 method=com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection; @ 23

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 131.684 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f9436718 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 131.686 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f9444298 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 131.689 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f9450ba0 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 131.696 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f9463278 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 131.701 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f946f0b8 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 131.704 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f947b410 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 133.651 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f9499c80 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 133.656 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f94b3c68 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 133.662 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f94cf308 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 133.667 Thread 0x000000000ba17800 Threw 0x00000000f94e9f10 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304

Events (10 events):
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep done
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: GetCurrentLocation
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: GetCurrentLocation done
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep done
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep
Event: 133.676 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep done
Event: 133.691 Executing VM operation: GetOrSetLocal
Event: 133.691 Executing VM operation: GetOrSetLocal done
```

Stack overflow wouldn't let me post the entire file because it is more than 30000 characters but the other sections in it are: Dynamic libraries, VM Arguments, Environment Variables, and System info. Let me know if this info is needed and I can respond with it in a comment or something.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379910/exception-access-violation-thrown-when-reading-a-video-from-a-file-with-xuggle/67870750#67870750). I answered with my experience there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that Xuggler sometimes has issues with 64-bit JRE. **I switched to a 32-bit JRE and it fixed the issue.**

To switch JRE in Eclipse:
Using Eclipse I right clicked on my project and went to Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries. Then I selected "JRE System Library" and clicked "Edit...". From there I chose "Alternate JRE:" and selected a "jre7-32-bit" and clicked "finish" and then "OK". If you do not already have a 32-bit JRE installed you my have to do that first.